# Calling a method everytime the text in JPasswordField is altered

Tags: java, swing, jpasswordfield

**--EDIT--**
I've got a JTextField and I want a method (let it be just print statement for now) to be called everytime someone changes (types or deletes) a character in the JTextField. The purpose behind it is for the method to instantly check whether whatever is typed satisfies certain conditions. Thanks to your help I managed to write:

```
public class MyDocumentListener implements DocumentListener {

    public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        updateLog(e, "inserted into");
    }
    public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        updateLog(e, "removed from");
    }
    public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        //Plain text components do not fire these events
    }

    public void updateLog(DocumentEvent e, String action) {
        System.out.println("should call the method here");
    }
}
```

The JTextField code:

```
    JTextField passwordField = new JTextField();
    passwordField.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new MyDocumentListener());
    passwordField.getDocument().putProperty("name", "Text Field");
```

The problem I'm getting now is that I need to use

```
String textFieldPassword = passwordField.getText();
```

but it returns `NullPointerException`. I am assuming that this is because I added the `DocumentListener` and should be operating on `DocumentEvent` now. But I don't really know how to do it.

Comment: Just get the Document and add a DocumentListener to it. Don't use a KeyListener since you shouldn't be using that with Swing and it won't respond to copy/paste actions.

Comment: Right. Just one quick question: can I use `passwordField.getText();` and treat it as a `String`?

Comment: no, shouldn't do this. The method is deprecated as you never want to treat a password as a String as Strings can persist making your password vulnerable. Better to treat it as an array of char.

Comment: *"want a method .. to be called everytime someone changes .. a character"*  Why?  What method?

Comment: Method to instantly check whether whatever is typed in satisfies certain conditions.

Answer (score 2):

You want an action listener for the field:

```
public class YourClass extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

    public void addComponents() {
        ...
        passwordField.addActionListener(this);
        ...
    }

    /**
      will be fired when the password field changes
    */
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        String text = passwordField.getText();
        System.out.println("key pressed");
    }
}
```

If that's not to your taste then you can try [DocumentListener](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0260__Swing-Event/ListeningtoJTextFieldEventswithaDocumentListener.htm).

Comment: Didn't work. 
`public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)`  
`{String text = passwordField.getText();`  `System.out.println("key pressed, value is "+text);` Second line of code gives NullPointerException - after I pressed "Enter" - just typing letters into the JPasswordField didn't give any effect.

Comment: -1 for the ActionListener. An ActionEvent is only fired when the Enter key is pressed, which does not satisfy the requirement. However, +1, for the DocumentListener. This is the solution that will satisfy the requirement. See [How to Write a Document Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html) for more information and examples.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I ended up with (to enable a button when 2 passwords match):

```
public class ChangePasswordUI implements DocumentListener, ActionListener {
    private JFrame frame;
    private JPasswordField newPassword1 = new JPasswordField(20);
    private JPasswordField newPassword2 = new JPasswordField(20);
    private JButton OKbutton;

    protected ChangePasswordUI() {
        OKbutton.addActionListener(this);
        newPassword1.addActionListener(this);
        newPassword2.addActionListener(this);
        newPassword1.getDocument().addDocumentListener(this);
        newPassword2.getDocument().addDocumentListener(this);

        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add(newPassword1);
        frame.add(newPassword2);
        frame.pack();
        updateOKbutton();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void updateOKbutton() {
        if(Arrays.equals(newPassword1.getPassword(),newPassword2.getPassword()) == false) {
            OKbutton.setEnabled(false);
        } else {
            OKbutton.setEnabled(true);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == cancelButton) {
            frame.dispose();
        } else if (e.getSource() == OKbutton) {
            frame.dispose();
        } else if (e.getSource() == newPassword1) {
            updateOKbutton();
        } else if (e.getSource() == newPassword2) {
            updateOKbutton();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        updateOKbutton();
    }

    @Override
    public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        updateOKbutton();
    }

    @Override
    public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        updateOKbutton();
    }
}
```

Notes:

- the example code is a stripped down version of a "set new password" dialog box I'm using, and the `JFrame` stuff is probably completely dodgy (I'm using a messy `GridBagLayout()` thing and nobody wants to see that)
- the `.getText()` method is deprecated now (you'd want to use `.getDocument()`).
- an `actionListener` is mostly useless for password fields (but probably needed for other things, so why not include that too!)